# Navigation to Library source code and not index

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I am using a custom Angular library (named core), imported from my main application.

Imports in my main App refer to the built `core/dist` index files:

```
import {SomeService} from 'core';
```

The `core` lib is referenced in tsconfig (the 2 entries were added by `ng generate library`):

```
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
  "core": [
    "dist/core/core",
    "dist/core"
  ]
},
```

The `ng build` works fine and I can run the app. But when I navigate from a main App file to a library component (Ctrl/Meta click), WebStorm directs me to the generated `core/dist/some/some.service.d.ts` index file. I would like it to direct me to the library component's source code `core/src/some/Some.service.ts`.

I tried declaring my `core` lib in WebStorm libraries, with no success. Am I missing something in my configuration ?

Comment: can't reproduce with similar steps, the IDE jumps to library `.ts` files and not to `d.ts` from `dist`. Is `dist` excluded from indexing, BTW? If it doesn't, try marking it excluded explicitly - does it help?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @lena. Yes the directory is correctly excluded by WebStorm. I'll try on a smaller project